# Is it good to store large data in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a scenario in which on a single page there is N number of Notepad(component). Notepad data can be in GB also. On successful saving of data I am storing it to the Redux store, So that next time(in view mode) I don't need to do API call for fetching the content. Suppose N no of Notepad is there having each one 1GB data then the Redux store will contain N*1Gb. Is it a good way to do things? Or I need to do API call each time to show data. What is the maximum capacity of storing data in redux?

Comment: Load what current context requires, that will be the better approach so when the user scrolls down you can have a loader and fetch data from api. Because loading all the data and assume the user never visited some notes then it will be waste of space and storing. Instead of calling a db call and fetching you can have a caching so you can avoid the expensive db calls every time and update the data when it actually gets updated.

Comment: On the scroll, the loading feature is not there. So is it good to store data in Redux? what will be the application performance? Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Mostly loading at the time or just before is the approach loading everything at initial load will make the page to respond fast. Are you using any grid layouts like the ui of google https://keep.google.com/

Comment: Yes like UI of google keep.goole.com.

Comment: Then you can use the same way, initial application load you can load little data on scroll to below you can load another more...